# @Html.ListBoxFor duplicated list

Tags: html, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I'm using `@Html.ListBoxFor` with a javascript script to make it more visually agreeable but the selection list appear duplicated. One of the selection list is the original and the other one is the script one. I'm developing in .NET core MVC using C#.

I'll put here only the essential code necessary  to understand what I'm doing.

**Model**

```
public class Property
{
    public Property()
    {
        SelectedCommodities = new List<int>();
    }
    //...
    //...
    //...
    [NotMappedAttribute]
    public List<int> SelectedCommodities { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller method who call view**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSecondPageAsync(int CategoryId)
{
    var CommoditiesList = await _context.CommoditiesList
        .Include(cL => cL.Commodities)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cL => (cL.CategoryId == CategoryId && cL.Default));

    ViewData["Commodities"] = new SelectList(CommoditiesList.Commodities, "CommodityId", "Name");
    ViewData["CategoryId"] = CategoryId;
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyAirbnb_G3.Models.Properties.Property
@*...*@
@*...*@
@*...*@
    <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="CommoditiesList" class="control-label"></label>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCommodities, (SelectList) ViewBag.Commodities , new { @class = "listbox" })
    </div>
@*...*@
@*...*@
@*...*@
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.listbox').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });
    </script>
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Why is that red circled list appearing and how can i make it disappear?!

Comment: You can try to check if the versions of css and js are right.

Comment: Actually i already changed my strategy and now i use a partial view instead but I'll try that thanks for your suggestion